# Error Sping Boot list all files in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-blob-storage, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to list all my files in my Azure container, but when I use the method .listBlobs( ) I can't get my List of BlobItems.

I received the error: *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.core.publisher.Mono.mapNotNull(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono;*

My BlobContainerClient is getting correctly the Connection String and the Container Name.

**Follow the code below:**

```
public List<String> listFiles() {
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = containerClient();
    PagedIterable<BlobItem> blobItems = containerClient.listBlobs();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BlobItem item : blobItems) {
        list.add(item.getName());
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.core.publisher.Mono.mapNotNull(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono;
at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.AsyncRestProxy.handleBodyReturnType(AsyncRestProxy.java:176) ~[azure-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.AsyncRestProxy.handleRestResponseReturnType(AsyncRestProxy.java:133) ~[azure-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.AsyncRestProxy.lambda$handleRestReturnType$8(AsyncRestProxy.java:210) ~[azure-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDelaySubscription$DelaySubscriptionMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxDelaySubscription.java:188) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:179) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1785) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:212) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:269) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:383) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:396) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:452) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:664) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1533) ~[netty-handler-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1294) ~[netty-handler-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1331) ~[netty-handler-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-08-10 15:41:13.653  WARN 12444 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] i.n.c.AbstractChannelHandlerContext      : An exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.core.publisher.Mono.mapNotNull(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono;' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.core.publisher.Mono.mapNotNull(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono;
at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.AsyncRestProxy.handleBodyReturnType(AsyncRestProxy.java:176) ~[azure-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.AsyncRestProxy.handleRestResponseReturnType(AsyncRestProxy.java:133) ~[azure-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.AsyncRestProxy.lambda$handleRestReturnType$8(AsyncRestProxy.java:210) ~[azure-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDelaySubscription$DelaySubscriptionMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxDelaySubscription.java:188) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:179) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1785) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:212) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:269) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:383) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:396) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:452) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:664) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1533) ~[netty-handler-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1294) ~[netty-handler-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1331) ~[netty-handler-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobcontainerclient.listblobs?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: @MohitGanorkar I used all of this methods mentioned in documentation, but none of them worked. Is the same error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post it here in case anyone encounters the same problem.

I found that the problem is the **version of my spring boot** because I'm using *2.4.0* and when I updated from *2.7.2* this worked normally.